# Rotation issue: How to print slides, 4-per-page, using CUPS lp

Tags: linux, cups, lp

I am trying to print 4-slides per page using CUPS lp (in landscape).

However, the pages do not emerge rotated no matter what I do.
(It looks terrible!)[image]

I get the same result whether:

1. I use CUPS to rotate, `-o orientation-requested=4`
2. if I use pdf90 to rotate, `pdf90 --suffix 'foo' file.pdf`
3. if I do nothing.

Here is the code I use:
`lp -o fit-to-page -o number-up=4 -o number-up-layout="btlr" -o page-border="single-thick" -o sides=two-sided-short-edge file.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot do it through `CUPS` alone,
but using

`pdf90 --suffix "90" file.pdf`

and then

`pdfpun file-90.pdf --outfile file-2x2.pdf --nup 2x2`,

I get the correct output (without the boxes around the individual slides)

P.S.
I still wonder if I just have an extra command in the `lp` call